# Quaternion-based First Person View Camera

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have been learning OpenGL by following the tutorial, located at https://paroj.github.io/gltut/.

Passing the basics, I got a bit stuck at understanding quaternions and their relation to spatial orientation and transformations, especially from world- to camera-space and vice versa. In the chapter *Camera-Relative Orientation*, the author makes a camera, which rotates a model in *world* space relative to the camera orientation. Quoting:

> We want to apply an orientation offset (R), which takes points in camera-space. If we wanted to apply this to the camera matrix, it would simply be multiplied by the camera matrix: R * C * O * p. That's nice and all, but we want to apply a transform to O, not to C.

My uneducated guess would be that if we applied the offset to camera space, we would get the first-person camera. Is this correct? Instead, the offset is applied to the model in *world* space, making the spaceship spin relative to that space, and not to camera space. We just observe it spin from camera space.

Inspired by at least some understanding of quaternions (or so I thought), I tried to implement the first person camera. It has two properties:

```
struct Camera{ 
  glm::vec3 position; // Position in world space.
  glm::quat orientation; // Orientation in world space.
}
```

Position is modified in reaction to keyboard actions, while the orientation changes due to mouse movement on screen.

Note: GLM overloads `*` operator for `glm::quat * glm::vec3` with the relation for rotating a vector by a quaternion (more compact form of `v' = qvq^-1`)

For example, moving forward and moving right:

```
glm::vec3 worldOffset;
float scaleFactor = 0.5f;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS) {
    worldOffset = orientation * (axis_vectors[AxisVector::AXIS_Z_NEG]); // AXIS_Z_NEG = glm::vec3(0, 0, -1)
    position += worldOffset * scaleFactor;
}
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS) {
    worldOffset = orientation  * (axis_vectors[AxisVector::AXIS_X_NEG]); // AXIS_Z_NEG = glm::vec3(-1, 0, 0)
    position += worldOffset * scaleFactor;
}
```

Orientation and position information is passed to `glm::lookAt` matrix for constructing the world-to-camera transformation, like so:

```
auto camPosition = position;
auto camForward = orientation * glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(camPosition, camPosition + camForward, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
```

Combining model, view and projection matrices and passing the result to vertex shader displays everything okay - the way one would expect to see things from the first-person POV. However, things get messy when I add mouse movements, tracking the amount of movement in x and y directions. I want to rotate around the *world* y-axis and *local* x-axis:

```
auto xOffset = glm::angleAxis(xAmount, axis_vectors[AxisVector::AXIS_Y_POS]); // mouse movement in x-direction
auto yOffset = glm::angleAxis(yAmount, axis_vectors[AxisVector::AXIS_X_POS]); // mouse movement in y-direction
orientation = orientation * xOffset; // Works OK, can look left/right
orientation = yOffset * orientation; // When adding this line, things get ugly
```

What would the problem be here?
I admit, I don't have enough knowledge to debug the mouse movement code properly, I mainly followed the lines, saying "right multiply to apply the offset in world space, left multiply to do it in camera space."

I feel like I know things half-way, drawing conclusions from a plethora of e-resources on the subject, while getting more educated and more confused at the same time.
Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To rotate a glm quaternion representing orientation:

```
//Precomputation: 
//pitch (rot around x in radians), 
//yaw (rot around y in radians), 
//roll (rot around z in radians)
//are computed/incremented by mouse/keyboard events
```

To compute view matrix:

```
void CameraFPSQuaternion::UpdateView()
{
  //FPS camera:  RotationX(pitch) * RotationY(yaw)
  glm::quat qPitch = glm::angleAxis(pitch, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
  glm::quat qYaw = glm::angleAxis(yaw, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
  glm::quat qRoll = glm::angleAxis(roll,glm::vec3(0,0,1));  

  //For a FPS camera we can omit roll
  glm::quat orientation = qPitch * qYaw;
  orientation = glm::normalize(orientation);
  glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(orientation);

  glm::mat4 translate = glm::mat4(1.0f);
  translate = glm::translate(translate, -eye);

  viewMatrix = rotate * translate;
}
```

If you want to store the quaternion, then you recompute it whenever yaw, pitch, or roll changes:

```
void CameraFPSQuaternion::RotatePitch(float rads) // rotate around cams local X axis
{
  glm::quat qPitch = glm::angleAxis(rads, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));

  m_orientation = glm::normalize(qPitch) * m_orientation;
  glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(m_orientation);

  glm::mat4 translate = glm::mat4(1.0f);
  translate = glm::translate(translate, -eye);

  m_viewMatrix = rotate * translate;
}
```

If you want to give a rotation speed around a given axis, you use slerp:

```
void CameraFPSQuaternion::Update(float deltaTimeSeconds)
{
  //FPS camera:  RotationX(pitch) * RotationY(yaw)
  glm::quat qPitch = glm::angleAxis(m_d_pitch, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
  glm::quat qYaw = glm::angleAxis(m_d_yaw, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
  glm::quat qRoll = glm::angleAxis(m_d_roll,glm::vec3(0,0,1));  

  //For a FPS camera we can omit roll
  glm::quat m_d_orientation = qPitch * qYaw;
  glm::quat delta = glm::mix(glm::quat(0,0,0,0),m_d_orientation,deltaTimeSeconds);
  m_orientation = glm::normalize(delta) * m_orientation;
  glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(orientation);

  glm::mat4 translate = glm::mat4(1.0f);
  translate = glm::translate(translate, -eye);

  viewMatrix = rotate * translate;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but what is the use-case of the SLERP here? I can perform two rotations by simply multiplying two quaternions representing them, without SLERPing. I am mainly interested in how I would correctly implement rotating around local x-axis - i.e. correct order of transformations between camera space and world space to achieve this.

Comment: @blairo SLERP is used for a smooth transition between the initial and final orientations. The method you are describing performs a discrete transition with no control over the rate of rotation.

Comment: This use case is based on you being able to set angular velocity around a given axis (as represented by delta_pitch etc). I'll update my answer with a more direct approach.

Comment: @IanYoung Hey! Will this camera account for Gimbal locks in case of Free look?

Comment: @VigneshGunasekaran Gimbal lock isn't really a problem with quaternions, as it essentially represents a vector, and a rotation angle around that vector. Gimbal lock is when your "up" vector, for example, ends up being the same as your "forward" vector, which breaks the view matrix. Quaternions neatly bipass that problem.

Comment: @IanYoung Hi, I stumbled upon this answer just know and wanted to ask you if there is a way to clap the local x rotation (pitch) with this method. E.g. only let the camera look down -89 or up 89 degree to stop it from rolling over. I am currently struggling to make this work.

Comment: @Symlink Apologies for the slow reply. Quaternions will not provide such functionality. You would have store the pitch value in a class member and add code to clamp the max/min value before using it to compute a quaternion.

Comment: what is the '-eye' variable? is it the camera 'position' member variable?

Comment: @Avi "eye" is the look direction, i.e. the direction the camera is pointing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lied with the usage of `glm::lookAt` for constructing the view matrix. Instead, I am now constructing the view matrix like so:

```
auto rotate = glm::mat4_cast(entity->orientation);
auto translate = glm::mat4(1.0f);
translate = glm::translate(translate, -entity->position);
viewMatrix = rotate * translate;
```

For translation, I'm left multiplying with an inverse of orientation instead of orientation now.

```
glm::quat invOrient = glm::conjugate(orientation);
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS) {
  worldOffset = invOrient * (axis_vectors[AxisVector::AXIS_Z_NEG]);
  position += worldOffset * scaleFactor;
}
...
```

Everything else is the same, apart from some further offset quaternion normalizations in the mouse movement code.

The camera now behaves and feels like a first-person camera.

I still don't properly understand the difference between view matrix and lookAt matrix, if there is any. But that's the topic for another question.